# How to add a cake php file in another cake php file

Tags: cakephp

I am using cake php now. I have two file example1.ctp and example2.ctp. I want to include example2.ctp in example1.ctp just like how we add php page using "include". I am new to this please suggest me how to do it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to me , You have to create Elements..

CakePHP can help you repeat parts of your website that need to be reused. These reusable parts are called Elements.

```
<?php echo $this->element('ur elements ctp file name'); ?>
```

Comment: Where do i need to create this because i have tried creating this in example1 but not finding the solution. Do i need to create element for example2 somewhere else